# Как убрать мигание в блоке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

при наведении есть мигание
врапперу меняется background

изначально ему задан liner-gradient
а когда наводим на итемы - просто background

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let image = $('.panel__item');
  let title = $('.panel__title');
  let defaultTitle = $('.panel__title').data('default');
  let defaultDesc = $('.panel__text p').data('default');
  let wrap = $('.panel');
  let desc = $('.panel__text p');
  image.on('mouseover', function() {
    
    let currentColor = $(this).data("color");
    let currentTitle = $(this).data("title");
    let currentDesc = $(this).data("text");
    wrap.css("background", currentColor);
    title.text(currentTitle);
    desc.text(currentDesc);

    image.addClass('panel__disabled');
    $(this).addClass('panel__active');
  })

  image.on('mouseout', function() {
    image.removeClass('panel__disabled');
    image.removeClass('panel__active');
    title.text(defaultTitle);
    desc.text(defaultDesc);
    wrap.attr('style', '')
  })
  
  
  });
```

```css
.panel {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #004386 0%, #0065CA 100%);
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s background;
}

.panel__title {
    font-size: 2.9375rem;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.panel__text {
    min-height: 42px;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.panel__text p {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.17;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel__wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.panel__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(100% / 5);
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.panel__item:hover .panel__link {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.panel__image {
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.panel__image img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: 0.4s opacity;
}

.panel__disabled {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.panel__active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="panel" style="">
        <div class="container container--panel">
             <h3 class="panel__title" data-default="title main">title main</h3>
             <div class="panel__text">
                 <p data-default="lorem">lorem</p>
             </div>
             <div class="panel__wrap">
                 <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#03a4c7" data-title="Заголовок продукта 1" data-text="Текст про продукт 1">
                    <picture class="panel__image">
                        <source srcset="img/panel/prod1_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod1_2x.png 2x">
                        <img src="img/panel/prod1_1x.png" alt="panel_1">
                    </picture>
                 </a>
                <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#f2a900" data-title="Заголовок продукта 2" data-text="Текст про продукт 2">
                    <picture class="panel__image">
                        <source srcset="img/panel/prod2_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod2_2x.png 2x">
                        <img src="img/panel/prod2_1x.png" alt="panel_2">
                     </picture>
                 </a>
                 <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#003087" data-title="Заголовок продукта 3" data-text="Текст про продукт 3">
                    <picture class="panel__image">
                        <source srcset="img/panel/prod3_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod3_2x.png 2x">
                         <img src="img/panel/prod3_1x.png" alt="panel_3">
                     </picture>
                 </a>
                <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#4f0641" data-title="Заголовок продукта 4" data-text="Текст про продукт 4">
                    <picture class="panel__image">
                        <source srcset="img/panel/prod4_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod4_2x.png 2x">
                         <img src="img/panel/prod4_1x.png" alt="panel_4">
                     </picture>
                 </a>
                <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#8db926" data-title="Заголовок продукта 5" data-text="Текст про продукт 5">
                    <picture class="panel__image">
                         <source srcset="img/panel/prod5_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod5_2x.png 2x">
                        <img src="img/panel/prod5_1x.png" alt="panel_5">
                     </picture>
                 </a>
             </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в фоне присутствует градиент, у которого (пока) допускается анимация только позиции и размера, но не цветов. Поэтому не трогаем фон, а заливку делаем с помощью внутренней тени:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let image = $('.panel__item');
  let title = $('.panel__title');
  let defaultTitle = $('.panel__title').data('default');
  let defaultDesc = $('.panel__text p').data('default');
  let wrap = $('.panel');
  let desc = $('.panel__text p');
  image.on('mouseover', function() {

    let currentColor = $(this).data("color");
    let currentTitle = $(this).data("title");
    let currentDesc = $(this).data("text");
    wrap.css("box-shadow", `inset 0 0 0 100vw ${currentColor}`);
    title.text(currentTitle);
    desc.text(currentDesc);

    image.addClass('panel__disabled');
    $(this).addClass('panel__active');
  })

  image.on('mouseout', function() {
    image.removeClass('panel__disabled panel__active');
    title.text(defaultTitle);
    desc.text(defaultDesc);
    wrap.attr('style', '')
  })

});
```

```css
.panel {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #004386 0%, #0065CA 100%);
  padding-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s box-shadow;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw #0000;
}

.panel__title {
  font-size: 2.9375rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.panel__text {
  min-height: 42px;
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.panel__text p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.17;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel__wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.panel__item:hover .panel__link {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.panel__image {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.panel__image img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: 0.4s opacity;
}

.panel__disabled {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.panel__active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="panel" style="">
  <div class="container container--panel">
    <h3 class="panel__title" data-default="title main">title main</h3>
    <div class="panel__text">
      <p data-default="lorem">lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel__wrap">
      <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#03a4c7" data-title="Заголовок продукта 1" data-text="Текст про продукт 1">
        <picture class="panel__image">
          <source srcset="img/panel/prod1_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod1_2x.png 2x">
          <img src="img/panel/prod1_1x.png" alt="panel_1">
        </picture>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#f2a900" data-title="Заголовок продукта 2" data-text="Текст про продукт 2">
        <picture class="panel__image">
          <source srcset="img/panel/prod2_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod2_2x.png 2x">
          <img src="img/panel/prod2_1x.png" alt="panel_2">
        </picture>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#003087" data-title="Заголовок продукта 3" data-text="Текст про продукт 3">
        <picture class="panel__image">
          <source srcset="img/panel/prod3_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod3_2x.png 2x">
          <img src="img/panel/prod3_1x.png" alt="panel_3">
        </picture>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#4f0641" data-title="Заголовок продукта 4" data-text="Текст про продукт 4">
        <picture class="panel__image">
          <source srcset="img/panel/prod4_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod4_2x.png 2x">
          <img src="img/panel/prod4_1x.png" alt="panel_4">
        </picture>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="panel__item" data-color="#8db926" data-title="Заголовок продукта 5" data-text="Текст про продукт 5">
        <picture class="panel__image">
          <source srcset="img/panel/prod5_1x.png 1x, img/panel/prod5_2x.png 2x">
          <img src="img/panel/prod5_1x.png" alt="panel_5">
        </picture>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо, извините, что не по теме. Не подскажете это пожалуйста?   (речь о тени в двух состояниях)

https://www.figma.com/file/cGVRzB7Z0ofzw0U3JHIjfG/AC.com.ua-(Copy)?node-id=0%3A1
  https://jsfiddle.net/ykchLvo3/

Comment: @olyaromanenko: не могу понять, о чём речь...

Comment: @ UModeL , 
 https://jsfiddle.net/5hybcew9/

Comment: вот если сравнить с  макетом. То в макете вроде чуть светлее что-то. Соответсвенно другая тень